# spring-data-mongodb nested document projection

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have **posts** collection with nested document **comments**. Simply document schema looks like this:

```
{
    "_id"     : ObjectId("5867e5e64f768509c59f9392"),
    "userId"  : 1,
    "comments": [
        {
            "id"  : 1,
            "text": "a"
        },
        {
            "id"  : 2,
            "text": "b"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to project only the requested comment. I found an acceptable solution. (Only comment object return solutions are also welcome)

```
> db.posts.find({userId: 1, 'comments.id': 1}, {'comments.$': 1});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5867e5e64f768509c59f9392"), "comments" : [ { "id" : 1, "text" : "a" } ] }
```

Then I try to apply it to mongodb repository interface with query annotation.

```
@Query(
    value = ""
        + "{"
        + "  'userId'     : '?1',"
        + "  'comments.id': '?2',"
        + "}",
    fields = "'comments.$'"
)
Note findComment(String userId, String commentId);
```

But i got cast exception. Is there a better way to do this with spring-data-mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @Query json is ill formed.

Try this.

```
@Query( value="{ 'userId' : ?0 , 'comments.id': ?1 }",  fields = "{ 'comments.$' : 1}")
```

Comment: Is there a way to return only comment data? `{ "id" : 1, "text" : "a" }`